# how to load specific class for html element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying UV index from json data, however I can't figure how to display the colour relevant to the UV index value.

so far here is what I have:

```js
document.getElementById("uvIndex").innerHTML = getUvIndex();

function getUvIndex() {
    miliVolts = 0;
    text = "UV Index: "
    if (miliVolts < 50) {
        text += " 0 <div style='width: 20px; height: 20px; display: inline-block";
        text += "background-color: rgba(0,190,0, 0.5); position: relative; left: 5px;";
        text += "top: 5px;background-color: rgba(0,190,0, 0.5);' ";
        text += "width='20'></div>";
        text += " <div>Exposure Level None - No Light</div>";
    }
    return text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="label label-default" id="uvIndex">Loading UV index.</div>
```

but what I am thinking from bootstrap, I can apply class i.e. `class="label label-default"`something other based on value.­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use HTML DOM className Property or jquery add class method.
Just customize it to your need.
HTML class name property example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.mystyle {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: coral;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to set a class for div.</p>

<div id="myDIV">
I am a DIV element
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDIV").className = "mystyle";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```